# force a div to scroll down

Tags: javascript

I'm building a private messaging service for my app and I'm having difficulty trying to make the messages view scroll to the bottom whenever a new message is added to the div.

I've seen numerous questions on stack overflow where the answer has been

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

but this doesn't seem to have worked.

I'm using angular 4 to build the app

Here's where I try to get the div to scroll down:

firstly when the app tries to get all the messages for a particular thread:

```
getMessagesForThread(){
    console.log("getting messages for: ");
    console.log(this.selectedThread);
    this.userService.getMessagesForThread(this.selectedThread.id, this.page).then(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        if(data.length >0){
            this.selectedThread.messages.unshift.apply(this.selectedThread.messages, data)
            //this.selectedThread = thread;
            console.log(this.selectedThread);
            if(this.page < this.selectedThread.count){
                this.canLoad = true;
            }else{
                this.canLoad = false;
            }
            var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
                console.log(objDiv.scrollHeight);
                console.log(objDiv.scrollTop);
                objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
        }

    })
}
```

and again when a new message is sent by the user:

```
shouldSend($event){
    //console.log($event);
    if ($event.keyCode == 13) {
        if($event.shiftKey){
            console.log("SHIFT + ENTER");

        }else{
            console.log("send message");
            let message = new Message("", this.selectedThread.id, this.user.id, $event.target.value);
            console.log(message);
            this.userService.sendMessage(message).then(data=>{
                this.defaultValue = '';
                this.selectedThread.messages.push(data);
                var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
                console.log(objDiv.scrollHeight);
                console.log(objDiv.scrollTop);
                objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

                console.log(objDiv.scrollTop);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

according to the console logs the problem is at `objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight` because the last `console.log(objDiv.scrollTop);` is the same result as the first.

can anyone see where I went wrong?

thanks

**EDIT**

this is the CSS used on the `messages` div

```
.messageScreen{
overflow:auto;
height: 70vh;
padding-top: 2%;
padding-bottom: 55px;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you can't change the value of `scrollTop`. I could be wrong.

Comment: but there is a way to do this, every online messaging system out there does it lol

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet it is possible: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp

Comment: What is the css of your messages div?

Comment: @H77 I've added that CSS class to the bottom of the question

Comment: I reckon the html hasn't actually updated when you're adjusting the scroll top. Maybe try updating scrollTop it in a setTimeout.

Comment: you're right, if you stick that down as an answer i'll mark it as the solution :)

Comment: Just added it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon the html hasn't actually updated when you're adjusting the scroll top.

Maybe try updating `scrollTop` from within a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

e.g.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
   console.log(objDiv.scrollHeight);
   console.log(objDiv.scrollTop);
   objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

   console.log(objDiv.scrollTop);
}, 100);
```